# manipulation of 2d-array in openmp

Tags: openmp

I write a loop of the 2d-array 'charge_density'. One specific element of this 2d-array is changed by adding a number to its original value every time. I'd like to speed this process up by openmp, but the reduction command  only support scale number. How should I solve this problem? This is a dll file which I use in ctypes for Python. Parameters of this function are from python. Here is my code:

```
void charge_distribute(double charge_density[][256], double position[][2], double x_range[], double y_range[], double x_step, double y_step)
{
    
    int column_index_left=0, column_index_right=0, row_index_up=0, row_index_down=0;
    int i = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(x_step,y_step,position,x_range,y_range) private(column_index_left,column_index_right,row_index_up,row_index_down) reduction(+:charge_density)
    for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        column_index_left = ((position[i][0] - x_range[0])) / x_step;
        column_index_right = column_index_left + 1;
        row_index_up = ((position[i][1] - y_range[0])) / y_step;
        row_index_down = row_index_up + 1;
        charge_density[row_index_up][column_index_left] = charge_density[row_index_up][column_index_left]+(1 - fabs(x_range[column_index_left] - position[i][0]) / x_step) * (1 - fabs(y_range[row_index_up] - position[i][1]) / y_step);
        charge_density[row_index_up][column_index_right] = charge_density[row_index_up][column_index_right]+(1 - fabs(x_range[column_index_right] - position[i][0]) / x_step) * (1 - fabs(y_range[row_index_up] - position[i][1]) / y_step);
        charge_density[row_index_down][column_index_left] = charge_density[row_index_down][column_index_left]+(1 - fabs(x_range[column_index_left] - position[i][0]) / x_step) * (1 - fabs(y_range[row_index_down] - position[i][1]) / y_step);
        charge_density[row_index_down][column_index_right] = charge_density[row_index_down][column_index_right]+(1 - fabs(x_range[column_index_right] - position[i][0]) / x_step) * (1 - fabs(y_range[row_index_down] - position[i][1]) / y_step);



    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. use reduction of an array (available since OpenMP 4.5). In this case you have to specify the size of array in the reduction clause: `reduction(+:charge_density[:array_size][:256])`
   Note that in this case a private copy of the array is created on the stack, so if your array is too big, it may cause stack overflow.
2. use atomic operations:

```
#pragma omp atomic
charge_density[row_index_up][column_index_left] += (1 - fabs(x_range[column_index_left] - position[i][0]) / x_step) * (1 - fabs(y_range[row_index_up] - position[i][1]) / y_step);
#pragma omp atomic
charge_density[row_index_up][column_index_right] += (1 - fabs(x_range[column_index_right] - position[i][0]) / x_step) * (1 - fabs(y_range[row_index_up] - position[i][1]) / y_step);
#pragma omp atomic
charge_density[row_index_down][column_index_left] += (1 - fabs(x_range[column_index_left] - position[i][0]) / x_step) * (1 - fabs(y_range[row_index_down] - position[i][1]) / y_step);
#pragma omp atomic
charge_density[row_index_down][column_index_right] += (1 - fabs(x_range[column_index_right] - position[i][0]) / x_step) * (1 - fabs(y_range[row_index_down] - position[i][1]) / y_step);
```